# Convert time strings to Excel time format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have some strings like this:

```
0 hours 13 minutes
1 hours 32 minutes
1 hours 10 minutes
0 hours 13 minutes
22 hours 5 minutes
0 hours 8 minutes
0 hours 1 minutes
0 hours 22 minutes
```

I want to convert them to time values so that I can do some calculations (average time).

I'm a bit stuck because some will have two digits hours/minutes and some only have 1. When I try to extract the values it seems to get confused and give me incorrect values.

I tried using a combination of the `LEFT` and `MID` formulas in conjunction with `MINUTE` and `HOUR` but have not been able to get a correct result. See below:

`Cell N2: 0 hours 37 minutes`

`Cell P2: =HOUR(LEFT(N2,2))`

`Cell Q2: =MINUTE(MID(N2,9,2))`

`Cell R2: =TIME(P2,Q2,0)`

This just returns 12:00AM or when formatted to `hh:mm` it says `00:00`. It should return `00:37`, or any other value that will allow me to get an average hour/minute value for any amount of these times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TIMEVALUE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"hours",":"),"minutes","")))
```

and format as **Time.**

[image]

Comment: I was about to submit `=LEFT(A1,2)/24+MID(A1,FIND(" minutes",A1)-2,2)/1440`, but this answer is neater. Incidentally, the `TRIM()` function is superfluous: `TIMEVALUE()` converts fine without it.